# Using a nested for loop and getting unexpected repetitions in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, for-loop

I've the following code in c# visual basic 2010:

```
for (int i = 7; i > 0; i--)
{
    Char star = '*';
    string numbers = "765432" ;

    //Console.WriteLine(star);

    for (int a = 0; a < i; a++)
    {
        Console.Write(star);
    }
    for (int b =  0; b < i; b++)
    {
        numbers.TrimEnd(numbers[numbers.Length - 1]);
        Console.Write(numbers);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();   
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

I was expecting the outcome:
`*765432`
repeated on the screen 7 times, instead I get:

```
*****765432765432765432765432765432

****765432765432765432765432

***765432765432765432

**765432765432

*765432
```

(I can't display the full outcome because it doesn't come back properly on screen but it's basically the variables star and numbers displayed 7 times on line 1, 6 times on line 2 etc. until once in line 7)

My understanding is that the `a` and `b` variables declared in the for loops should dictate how many times the for loop is entered into, why are the star and numbers variables also being written 7 times then 6 times to match the number of times the loop is entered into? Especially when they are initialised as `*` and `765432`?

Comment: Fire up the debugger and step through your code?

Comment: Strings are immutable.  TrimEnd is returning the resulting string.

Comment: @millimoose I have but the values of the variables stay the same, are never given multiple number of times

Comment: @PeterHuene what about star (*)?

Comment: c# visual basic 2010?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the problem (I suspect, anyway - it's certainly *a* problem):

```
numbers.TrimEnd(numbers[numbers.Length - 1]);
```

Strings are immutable in .NET. [`TrimEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx) doesn't change the *existing* string - it returns a reference to a new one. As highlighted in the documentation:

> This method does not modify the value of the current instance. Instead, it returns a new string in which all trailing characters found in `trimChars` are removed from the current string.

You'd also be better off using [`Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) for simplicity to "remove" the last character:

```
numbers = numbers.Substring(0, numbers.Length - 1);
```

Or indeed [`Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad138yc.aspx):

```
numbers = numbers.Remove(numbers.Length - 1);
```

... although this will actually fail on the 7th iteration as the string will be empty at this point. It's not really what you were trying to achieve, but I think you need to take a step back from it and think carefully about each step in the process.

Comment: +1 for "Step back and think carefully".. I don't think code is even close to what he wants, given the "expected outcome" bit.

Answer (score 2):

`TrimEnd` returns a new string, it doesn't modify the original string. You have to assign it back to number. Strings are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

```
number = numbers.TrimEnd(numbers[numbers.Length - 1]);
```

Check for string length before indexing its element. In your for loop you can add the condition like:

```
for (int b = 0; b < i && numbers.Length > 0; b++)
```

Answer (score 1):

No.  The 'a' for loop runs, outputting that many stars, and the 'b' for loop runs next, outputting that many strings.  If you just want '*765432' to repeat 7 times, you need to change

```
for (int a = 0; a < i; a++)
{
Console.Write(star);
}
for (int b =  0; b < i; b++)
{
numbers.TrimEnd(numbers[numbers.Length - 1]);
Console.Write(numbers);
}
```

To

```
for (int a = 0; a < 7; a++)
{
Console.Write(star);
Console.Write(numbers);
}
```

And take out the parent loop; that's what is giving you the incrementingly shorter lines.

Answer (score 0):

This produce the output you are expecting:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    Char star = '*';
    string numbers = "765432" ;

    Console.WriteLine(star);
    Console.Write(numbers);
    Console.WriteLine();   
}
```

I was expecting the outcome: *765432 repeated on the screen 7 times

Answer (score 0):

You never need to use `TrimEnd()` and multiple for loop in this situation.

```
  public static void Main()
        {
            for (int i = 7; i > 0;i--)
            {
                char star = '*';
                string numbers = "765432";
                Console.WriteLine(star + numbers);

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

output:

> ```
> *765432
> *765432
> *765432
> *765432
> *765432
> *765432
> *765432
> ```